# ggplot - bar chart with multiple y-variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a bar chart with three y-variables (`Total_us_received`, `Total_us_required`, `Total_us_received_from.CERF`) using ggplot2. All three y-variables are measured on the same scale (US$).

This far I've created a bar chart with Total_us_received as the y-variables and Disaster_category as the x-variable using this code:

```
ggplot(Template.2006.2017.text, 
       aes(Disaster_category, y=Total_US_received)) + 
  geom_bar(stat ="identity", fill="lightblue") + 
  coord_flip()
```

However, every attempt I've made to include the other two y-variables into the graph have failed. How can I include the other two variables into the graph?

A follow-up questions: Can I make the graph show the mean of every category of the x-variable (Disaster_subtype) without NA:s instead of the total sum?

Here's my data in dput (compressed version):

```
structure(list(Disaster_category = structure(c(1L, 15L, 17L, 
15L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 7L, 
2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 
15L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 15L, 8L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 
8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 15L, 
2L, 15L, 15L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 2L, 15L, 
8L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 
8L, 2L, 15L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 
8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 
8L, 15L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 
15L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("", " ", "Disease", "Disease related disaster", 
"Drought", "Drought & storm", "Extreme temperature / fire", "Flood", 
"Flood & drought", "Insect infestation", "Insect infestation & drought", 
"Landslide & flood", "Landslide / mudslide", "Other", "Storm", 
"Storm & flood", "Winter"), class = "factor"), Total_US_received_from.CERF = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 678307.8333, 
678307.8333, 678307.8333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1110469.5, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1905355, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2493246, 
2493246, 2493246, 2493246, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 333333.3333, 333333.3333, 333333.3333, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9365420, 
NA, NA, 14321419, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Total_US_received = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15507224.5, 15507224.5, 15507224.5, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 333333.3333, 333333.3333, 
    333333.3333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Total_US_required = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 20502064.83, 20502064.83, 20502064.83, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3070192, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 49955895.25, 49955895.25, 49955895.25, 49955895.25, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 333333.3333, 
    333333.3333, 333333.3333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There are various ways to make a bar chart. Do you want the values from `Total_us_received` / `Total_us_required` / `Total_us_received_from.CERF` stacked on top of each other? Side by side? It would be easier to understand your use case if you can sketch out what you have in mind. Also, note that your dataset consists of mostly NAs, which won't be plotted.

Comment: I want them side by side. And I'm aware of the NA:s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform you data into long format and then plot them:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

my_data %>% 
 gather(Total_US_category, Total_US, Total_US_received, Total_US_required, Total_US_received_from.CERF) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Disaster_category, y = Total_US, fill = Total_US_category)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

If you want to plot the mean-value per disaster you can first summarize the data with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data_sum <- my_data %>% 
  gather(Total_US_category, Total_US, Total_US_received, Total_US_required, Total_US_received_from.CERF) %>% 
  group_by(Disaster_category, Total_US_category) %>% 
  summarize(Total_US_mean = mean(Total_US, na.rm = T)) 

my_data_sum
# A tibble: 33 x 3
# Groups:   Disaster_category [?]
#    Disaster_category        Total_US_category           Total_US_mean
#    <fct>                    <chr>                               <dbl>
#  1 ""                       Total_US_received                     NaN
#  2 ""                       Total_US_received_from.CERF           NaN
#  3 ""                       Total_US_required                     NaN
#  4 " "                      Total_US_received                     NaN
#  5 " "                      Total_US_received_from.CERF           NaN
#  6 " "                      Total_US_required                     NaN
#  7 Disease                  Total_US_received                     NaN
#  8 Disease                  Total_US_received_from.CERF           NaN
#  9 Disease                  Total_US_required                     NaN
# 10 Disease related disaster Total_US_received                     NaN
# ... with 23 more rows
```

And then plot the data:

```
ggplot(my_data_sum, aes(Disaster_category, y = Total_US_mean, fill = Total_US_category)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kath! However, I get following error when running that code: Error in starts_with("Total_US") : could not find function "starts_with"

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! The `dplyr`-package is needes as well, or you can simply specify Total_us_received, Total_us_required, Total_us_received_from.CER

Comment: That worked out. However, since one bar is much longer than the others the graph looks pretty weird. Maybe that can be adjusted somehow.

Comment: A follow-up questions: Can I make the graph show the mean of every category of the x-variable (Disaster_subtype) excluding NA:s instead of the total sum?

Comment: Thanks again! By the way, is it possible to place the color boxes showing the different categories' color underneath the chart?

Comment: Add `+ theme(legend.position = "bottom")`. In general have a look at the reference for [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html) for more information how to modify your plot